# Scala strange error when using foldRight with operator syntax

Tags: scala, fold

```
1 to 5 foldRight (0)(x:Int, y:Int => x+y)
```

I am trying to add all the values from right to left with 0 as the initial parameter. I get the following error

```
Int(0) does not take parameters
```

Can anyone explain to me what this error even means? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just the parser getting "confused", so it's trying to apply `(x: Int, y: Int ...`) as argument of `(0)`.

Specifically, what you're using is a scala syntactic feature that allows to use

```
a.f(b)
```

as

```
a f b
```

This works with any method that has a single parameter. However when your method has multiple parameter lists (like `foldRight`), you have to use extra care.

This is what the parser sees

```
1 to 5  foldRight (0)(x: Int, y: Int => x + y)
|__a__| |___f___| |____________b_____________|
```

So when evaluating `b`, it treats 0 as a function with `(x: Int, ...)` as an argument.
Clearly this can't work, because `"Int(0) does not take parameters"`.

Instead, you can use

```
(1 to 5).foldRight(0)((x,y) => x + y)
```

or even

```
(1 to 5).foldRight(0)(_ + _)
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriele. This is a good explanation. Is there a more descriptive title for this question than what is wrong with this scala code.

Comment: Probably something like, "strange error when using foldRight with operator syntax"

Answer (score -1):

There are two things wrong with your code. The first is that you need to use brackets around `1 to 5`, the second is the syntax of your anonymous function. You need brackets around the parameters there.

```
(1 to 5).foldRight(0)((x,y) => x + y)
```

Comment: Aren't operators in scala left associative other than when they end with a :

Comment: the right associativity part is wrong. Try `1 to 5 map (_ + 1)`

Comment: @AbdulRahman you're correct, scala operators are right associative only when ending with `:`

Comment: Ultimately, the proposed code is correct, but the explanation is not. Yes you need brackets around the parameters, but that's not related to the OP's error. The operator syntax machinery is what's causing the strange error, but right-associativity is not the reason for it

Comment: @KimStebel thanks. The explanation you give is still unrelated though. What does the trick is actually not using the operator syntax